# Transport agnostic IMAP client implementation in Java?

Tags: jakarta-mail, netty, imap, nio, james

**Objective:**

An IMAP client running on top of *Netty* **OR** NIO

**Problem:**

No such thing seems to exist. So I am attempting to put together something myself. I have a faily good grasp on *Netty* but what I am missing is a lib/routines I can delegate encoding/decoding the IMAP protocol to + the session/state from the client side to put it on top of *Netty*

**What I looket at:**

[Apache James Protocols IMAP4](https://james.apache.org/protocols/imap4.html)
The project has a complete implementation of IMAP4 from the **server** side of things. And it actually runs on top of *Netty*. However, after looking at the code, I don't think I can easily use it to the flip side (the client) of IMAP communication

[JavaMail API reference implementation](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home)
This obviously has the client side, but the whole project seems to assume it's running on OIO aka blocking IO, so again it seems that putting *Netty* underneath is not trivial

[imapnio on Github](https://github.com/lafaspot/imapnio)
I found this library, but it's a very incomplete implementation of IMAP over NIO (via *Netty*).

I am definetely not implementing IMAP protocol routines myself.
Anything I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer to your question is that what you're looking for doesn't exist.

There's a longer discussion we could have about what problem you're trying to solve and how you might best go about solving it, but stackoverflow isn't the right place for that.  Feel free to contact me at javamail_ww@oracle.com.

Answer (score 0):

Half baked, but still, something I put together in my spare time that can hopefuly turn into production ready IMAP library for Java, that I hoped to find when I was searching for it.

https://gitlab.com/artur.jablonski.pl/async-imap-client